# How can I get size in bytes of an object sent using RMI?

Tags: java, stream, size, inputstream, rmi

I'm implementing a cache server with MongoDB and ConcurrentHashMap java class. When there are available space to put object in memory, it will put at. Otherwise, the object will be saved in a mongodb database. Is allowed that user specify a size limit in memory (this should not exceed heap size limit obviously!) for the memory cache. The clients can use the cache service connecting through RMI. I need to know the size of each object to verify if a new incoming object can be put into memory. I searched over internet and i got this solution to get size:

```
  public long getObjectSize(Object o){
    try {

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        oos.writeObject(o);
        oos.close();

        return bos.size();      
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Long.MAX_VALUE;
    }
}
```

This solution works very well. But, in terms of memory use doesn't solve my problem. :( If many clients are verifying the object size at same time this will cause stack overflow, right? Well... some people can say: Why you don't get the specific object size and store it in memory and when another object is need to put in memory check the object size? This is not possible because the objects are variable in size. :(

Someone can help me? I was thinking in get socket from RMI communication, but I don't know how to do this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the problem of limiting the size of serialized objects using a custom FilterOutputStream that:

1. counts the bytes that are written by the `write` method calls, and
2. throws a custom `IOException` subclass when the count exceeds your limit.

Then put this filter between the `ByteArrayOutputStream` and the `ObjectOutputStream`.

This is what the code would look like (not tested!):

```
    public LimitExceededException extends IOException { ... }

    public class LimitingOutputStream extends FilterOutputStream {
        private int limit;
        private int count;

        public LimitingOutputStream(OutputStream out, int limit) {
            super(out);
            this.limit = limit;
        }

        @Override
        public void write(byte b) throws IOException {
            if (count++ > limit) {
                throw LimitExceededException(...);
            }
            super.write(b);
        }

        @Override
        // (This override is not strictly necessary, but it makes it faster)
        public void write(byte[] bytes, int from, int size) throws IOException {
            if (count += size > limit) {
                throw LimitExceededException(...);
            }
            super.write(bytes, from, size);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return the serialization of `o` in a byte array, provided that it is
     * less than `limit` bytes.  If it is too big, return `null`.
     */
    public byte[] serializeWithLimit(Object o, int limit) {
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            LimitingOutputStream los = new LimitingOutputStream(bos, limit);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(los);
            oos.writeObject(o);
            oos.close();
            return bos.toByteArray(); 
        } catch (LimitExceededException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

<sup>Yes, this uses exceptions to "get out" when the limit is exceeded, but this is IMO a **good** use of exceptions.  And I **challenge** anyone who disagrees with that to come up with a better solution.  Put it in another Answer.</sup>

---

By the way, this is REALLY BAD code:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    return Long.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

In addition to the `IOException`s that you might expect to be thrown, you are also catching all manner of unchecked exceptions, most of which would be caused by bugs ... that you need to know about:

1. It is bad practice to catch `Exception` except when you are trying to do a last-ditch diagnosis.
2. Whenever you catch unexpected exceptions, be sure to log them so that the stack trace can be recorded (depending on the logger configurations).  Or if your application doesn't use a logging framework, then have it call `e.printStackTrace()`.

<sup>(And if you wouldn't do this in production code, don't do it into a StackOverflow Question either ... 'cos some copy-and-paste coder might just copy it.)</sup>

Comment: The use of an Uncaught exception is a bad practice in terms of logging only or there are some implication in terms of performance?

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek - "... which also means that you probably shouldn't throw one from the byte-counting FilterOutputStream either."  Feel free to suggest a better solution then.  Serializing an object larger than the user-imposed limit IS an *exceptional condition*.

Comment: @StephenC - I would think that a user attempting to violate the limit would not be unusual, and so should be handled by the application. A method that counts bytes should do just that - count bytes, and return the size. A separate method should decide if this violates some limit, and return a boolean. An exception should be reserved for when something really unexpected happens.

Comment: The exception police strike again. You start to wonder whether there is anything anywhere that exceptions *can* be used for. @GreyBeardedGeek If it is so usual why is the OP trying to prevent it?

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek - I have put a "complete" implementation into the Answer.  **I challenge you** to do likewise (in another Answer) to demonstrate your assertion that a solution without exceptions is better.  Bear in mind that a solution has to satisfy the stated requirement that it won't fill the heap if the serialized object is larger than the limit.

Comment: @StephenC - Challenge accepted. See my answer. Note that the decision to use or not use exceptions is a stylistic one, so 'better' is in the eye of the beholder, but limiting the use of exceptions to exceptional conditions, and not using them for data validation is pretty widely accepted. BTW, my first reaction to your challenge was to wonder why you seem to have a chip on your shoulder about this. Care to explain?

Comment: @GrayBeardedGeek - It depends whether you consider wasting lots and lots of time "writing" stuff that is being ignored a "stylistic" choice.  I personally would call it a major implementation flaw.  Do I have a chip on my shoulder?  No.  But I do get irritated by people who recite the "Exceptions should only be used for exceptional conditions" mantra without understanding its nuances.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my response to the challenge of implementing the requested functionality without using exceptions. It's a relatively minor re-working of the previous answer by @StephenC, except that this one actually compiles and works.

```
 import java.io.*;

 public class LimitingOutputStream extends FilterOutputStream {
     private int limit;
     private int count;
     private boolean limitExceeded = false;

     public LimitingOutputStream(OutputStream out, int limit) {
         super(out);
         this.limit = limit;
     }

     public boolean isLimitExceeded() {
         return limitExceeded;
     }

     @Override
     public void write(int b) throws IOException {

         if(!limitExceeded) {
            if(count++ > limit) {
                limitExceeded = true;
            } else {
                super.write(b);
            }
         }
     }

     @Override
     // (This override is not strictly necessary, but it makes it faster)
     public void write(byte[] bytes, int from, int size) throws IOException {
         if(!limitExceeded) {
            if ( (count += size) > limit) {
                limitExceeded = true;
            } else {
                super.write(bytes, from, size);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return the serialization of `o` in a byte array, provided that it is
     * less than `limit` bytes.  If it is too big, return `null`.
     */
    public static byte[] serializeWithLimit(Object o, int limit) throws IOException {
         ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         LimitingOutputStream los = new LimitingOutputStream(bos, limit);
         ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(los);
         oos.writeObject(o);
         oos.close();
         return los.isLimitExceeded() ? null : bos.toByteArray(); 
    }

 }
```

Comment: Oh great.  Rather than throwing an exception to say we've failed, we allow the next level up to keep writing, and writing, and writing.  Do you **seriously** think that is better that throwing an exception?